# How do I create a Login view with django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer and a view for my login like this.

```
class LoginView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class= LoginSerializer
    queryset=User.objects.all()

    error_messages = {
        'invalid': "Invalid username or password",
        'disabled': "Sorry, this account is suspended",
    }

    def _error_response(self, message_key):
        data = {
            'success': False,
            'message': self.error_messages[message_key],
            'user_id': None,
        }
    def post(self,request):
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)

                return Response(status=status.HTTP_100_OK)
            return self._error_response('disabled')
        return self._error_response('invalid')
```

and the serializer:

```
class LoginSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model=User
         fields=('email','password')
```

My url:

```
(r'^login/$',LoginView.as_view())
```

When I run the code I get an error
 **ImproperlyConfigured at /login/
Expected view LoginView to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.**

I currently do not have redirecting in my view.
what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are used [`generic.RetrieveAPIView`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views#retrieveapiview) which extends [`RetrieveModelMixin`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views#retrievemodelmixin) and [`GenericAPIView`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views#genericapiview), as per docs it need `pk` or you have to set `.lookup_field` in your class.

`RetrieveAPIView` is used to `get` and `get` means retrieve data and to retrieve data it need `pk`.

Use another class to handle your `POST`

Comment: Which class uses POST as the only means to derive data? What class should I be using?

Comment: you are using `generics.RetrieveAPIView`, please check its documentation.